# VBA to Update and Replace in Workbooks causes crashing

Tags: excel, vba

Please bear with me. My code is probably complete shit, so I appreciate all feedback! So what this does is, on my main workbook, there are a bunch of UNC hyperlinks in Row M, that link to files in a section drive.

What this code does:

1. Go down the list of hyperlinks in Column M, opens them up and executes the code inside of the "With WBSsource".
2. First, it searches for instances of the incorrect filepath (st) inside each of the cells formulas (NOT VALUES), and increments a counter using InStr (t), then after the worksheet has been searched, if the final count (c) is more than 0, meaning the search found at least one incorrect filepath, it will proceed to the next step.
3. It does a Cells.Replace on a worksheet (ws.) basis (at the FORMULA level)
4. Cells per worksheet are all done, it should save the workbook and close it before moving onto the next one.
5. Any links that could not be opened will appear in a final popup.

It is by Step 3 that it starts to run sluggish and crash.

I'm trying my best to get this automated and saving the workbooks. Then, once they're all updated, running this code again would be much faster cause it won't have to replace everything again.

```
Sub List_UpdateAndSave()
Dim lr As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim WBSsource As Workbook
Dim FileNames As Variant
Dim msg As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim r As Range, t As Long, c As Integer

' Update the individual credit models
With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
    FileNames = .Range("M2:M" & lr).Value
End With
For i = LBound(FileNames, 1) To UBound(FileNames, 1)
    On Error Resume Next
    If FileNames(i, 1) Like "*.xls*" Then
        Set WBSsource = Workbooks.Open(FileNames(i, 1), _
                                       ReadOnly:=False, _
                                       Password:="", _
                                       UpdateLinks:=3)


            If Err = 0 Then
            With WBSsource
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                ActiveWorkbook.Final = False
                Application.ScreenUpdating = False
                Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
                Application.EnableEvents = False

                st = "\\corp\Accounts\" 'Search Phrase
                n = "\\corp\StackOverflow\Accounts\" 'New Phrase
                c = 0

                For Each ws In WBSsource.Worksheets
                    ws.Activate
                    t = 0
                    On Error Resume Next
                    For Each r In ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
                        t = InStr(1, r.Formula, st)
                        If t > 0 Then
                            c = c + 1
                        End If
                    Next r
                Next ws

                If c > 0 Then
                    'MsgBox ws.Name & Chr(10) & (c)
                    ws.Cells.Replace st, n
                End If


                .UpdateLink Name:=ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources, Type:=xlExcelLinks
                Application.EnableEvents = True
                Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
                Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                .Save
                .Close True

            End With
        Else
            msg = msg & FileNames(i, 1) & Chr(10) & Chr(10)
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    End If

    Set WBSsource = Nothing
Next i
If Len(msg) > 0 Then
    'MsgBox "The Following Files Could Not Be Opened" & _
    '       Chr(10) & msg, 48, "Error"

    Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
        objShell.Popup "The Following Files Could Not Be Opened" & _
           Chr(10) & Chr(10) & msg, 48, "Error"
End If

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely crap. I just learned that we could create an array with this.

`FileNames = .Range("M2:M" & lr).Value`

It may crash since there's no range limit on the 3rd step. Try getting the last row and column on each worksheet, then create a range based on that.

```
With ws
    ' Get end cells
    With .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
        intLastRow = .Row
        intLastCol = .Column
    End With

    For each r in .Range(.Cells(1,1), .Cells(intLastRow, intLastCol))
        ' Check formula if it contains specific string
        t = InStr(1, r.Formula, st)
        If t > 0 Then
            c = c + 1
        End If

        ' Replace formula with new string
        r.Formula = Replace(r.Formula, st, n)
    Next r
End With
```

**Edit:** Here's the full code. Let me know if this works for you.

```
Option Explicit

' Update the individual credit models
Sub List_UpdateAndSave()
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' Declaration
    Dim i As Long
    Dim arrLinks As Variant
    Dim strLinksErr As String

    ' Initialization
    Dim strPathCur As String: strPathCur = "\\corp\Accounts\" ' search phrase
    Dim strPathNew As String: strPathNew = "\\corp\StackOverflow\Accounts\" ' new phrase

    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        ' Get links from sheet
        arrLinks = .Range("M2:M" & .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row).Value
    End With

    For i = LBound(arrLinks, 1) To UBound(arrLinks, 1)
        ' Check for Excel links
        If VBA.InStr(1, arrLinks(i, 1), ".xls", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            FnExcelUpdateLinks arrLinks(i, 1), strPathCur, strPathNew
        Else
            ' Add to list of links that could not be opened
            strLinksErr = strLinksErr & arrLinks(i, 1) & Chr(10)
        End If
    Next i

ErrorHandler:
    ' Display any errors
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error " & Err.Number

    ' Display any non-Excel links
    If strLinksErr <> "" Then
        MsgBox "The following files could not be opened:" & _
                Chr(10) & strLinksErr, 48, "Error"
    End If

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
End Sub


Function FnExcelUpdateLinks(ByVal strWbkPath As String, ByRef strPathCur As String, ByRef strPathNew As String)
    Dim intLastRow As Long, intLastCol As Long
    Dim wbkTmp As Workbook
    Dim shtTmp As Worksheet
    Dim rngCell As Range

    ' Open link as workbook
    Set wbkTmp = Workbooks.Open(strWbkPath, ReadOnly:=False, Password:="", UpdateLinks:=3)

    With wbkTmp
        For Each shtTmp In .Worksheets
            With shtTmp
                ' Get end cells
                With .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
                    intLastRow = .Row
                    intLastCol = .Column
                End With

                For Each rngCell In .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(intLastRow, intLastCol))
                    If VBA.InStr(1, rngCell.Formula, strPathCur) > 0 Then
                         rngCell.Formula = Replace(rngCell.Formula, strPathCur, strPathNew)
                    End If
                Next rngCell
            End With
        Next shtTmp

        .UpdateLink Name:=.LinkSources, Type:=xlExcelLinks
        .Save
        .Close True
    End With
End Function
```